# Translating "to pity myself"

Tags: traduction

Deepl says "I have got to stop pitying myself" is given by « Je dois arrêter de m'apitoyer sur moi-même ». The reflexive on *apitoyer* makes the *moi-même* seem redundant to me and the translation of *to pity myself* seems a bit convoluted here. Is Deepl's way the best way to express this sentence?

Comment: Deepl and company are not a measure of anything. Are we being asked to edit that?

Comment: avoir pitié de moi-même.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**:
The reason why it's not redundant is because the verb "apitoyer" is not equivalent to "pity" in English. Instead, it means something like "create a feeling of pity". The reflexive form "s'apitoyer" means "create a feeling of pity felt by yourself" or simply understood as "feel pity", but you still have to mention about what.

---

The word or emotion "pity" is more flexible in English and you can use it both as a verb and a noun. In French, we can't use pity as a verb. We either *have pity for* (avoir pitié) or we *feel pity for* (ressentir de la pitié).

Now, we do have the verb "apitoyer", which means "susciter la pitié". I have a hard time finding a good translation for "susciter" because I don't think the English language has this verb. I found online "create, arouse, excite, etc", but think of it as a verb meaning all of these in one term.

Knowing this, if you try to "apitoyer" someone, you will try to create or arouse a feeling of pity for something. If you use the reflexive form of this verb, you're now creating a feeling of pity felt by yourself, but we still don't know about what. Here's some literal translations:

- Je dois arrêter d'avoir pitié de moi-même (I have to stop having/feeling pity for myself).
- Je cherche à l'apitoyer sur mon sort (I'm trying to "create" a feeling [by him] of pity towards myself).
- Je dois arrêter de m'apitoyer sur mon sort (I have to stop "creating" a feeling [by me] of pity towards myself).

Notice that I used "mon sort" because "s'apitoyer sur son sort" is a set phrase in French meaning the same thing and will probably be preferred by a native speaker with the verb "apitoyer". Keep in mind that "s'apitoyer" is adding a stronger connotation. The "creation" (susciter) of the pity feeling adds a certain nuance. When you say "m'apitoyer", you also get the feeling of you contributing to it voluntarily in a detrimental manner, it's roughly equivalent to: "I have to stop [making me] pity myself [because it prevents me from doing things and evolve, move on, etc.]". The first example is simply "I feel pity towards myself", without the stronger nuance.

Comment: i want to thank you for putting the effort into this reply; i know it can take a lot of effort to write such in-depth answers. it's these kinds of nuances (between different, but related, verbs) that are difficult for learners of French for me to learn; but posts like yours help build the neural pathways that will help develop an intuition for such nuances.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not redundant. The reflexive pronoun refers to who feels pity, and what comes after is what that person feels pity about.

For *apitoyer*, the [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/apitoyer#Verbe) gives as one of the examples:

> Rien ne put l’apitoyer sur mon sort.

"*mon sort*" here meaning "my fate", "my lot".

The pronoun *l'* and the object *mon sort* point to different people.